# Cygwin Installation Hangs - man-db

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to Install Cygwin 64 bit on a Windows 2012R2 (64 bit).
Downloading and initial setup went through but when it reached man-db (/etc/postinstall/man-db) the setup hangs
and remains so forever. I waited more than 1.5 Hours but still no progress.
I checked log file in /var/log/setup.log which has following contents.

```
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/man1'. Wait...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
/usr/bin/mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man1/col.1.gz: whatis parse for col(1) failed
/usr/bin/mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man1/imv.1 is a dangling symlink
/usr/bin/mandb: iconv_open ("UTF-8//IGNORE", "utf8"): Invalid argument
/usr/bin/mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man1/mc.1.gz: whatis parse for mc(1) failed
```

I am not sure if I should cancel and start again. Will this setup come out of this stage with at least some error?
Did anyone install 64 bit Cygwin and got this error ? 
Please help

Comment: I ran into this the past two nights with both a Cygwin32 and a Cygwin64; I left them on overnight 7~8hours and both finally finished.

Answer (score 6):

Happens to me often. I was setting up 8 servers this week and it happened to 3 of them. Waited many hours and it is still would not finish. Sometimes the re-installation works, some it does not. So I have resorted to kill the **mandb.exe** process and that allows the installer to finish normally. So far I have found no side effects of doing so.

Comment: I believe this answer was correct for me - In Windows 7 I ran task manager and killed the mandb.exe process from the processes tab and it did finish correctly.

Comment: Running Task Manager as admin, I had to kill the bash.exe process rather than the mandb.exe process.  It gave me an access denied error (!) on mandb.exe, but when I killed the parent bash process, setup moved on.  However, after setup, it turned out mandb was still running and I had to kill it with "End Task" rather than "End Process Tree."

Answer (score 2):

After waiting for more than 3 hours, I decided to cancel the setup.  Then I tried a reinstall, following the steps exactly as in the first install. I did not add or remove any packages.  The already selected packages in the first attempt were recognized as installed. This time, the setup stopped at the above step (man-db) briefly and then completed the installation. No errors. So, re-installation solved my problem.

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work for me. I canceled as you did, reinstalled, but it still hangs on the man-db step.... This is for 32-bit Cygwin by the way

Comment: May be you can cancel the setup again and try to run the command manually  /usr/bin/mandb -c   (see this https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg135909.html  and http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-06/msg00298.html)

Comment: ok, I ran /usr/bin/mandb -c. It ran for several minutes, and although it generated several seemingly unrelated errors or warnings, it finished with 0 exit code (not that it means anything.) Difficult to tell whether it was successful or not. Is there some way to test it?

Comment: I searched and found that 'A process is considered to have completed correctly in Linux if its exit status is 0'. Now Cygwin successful installation in general ends with the standard dialog box which says 'setup complete'. What you can now do is, start Cygwin update (which is similar to install), do not add any extra package. Since man-db is already installed, it will not get stuck at that stage. So you should get the 'setup complete' message. If you don't want to do this re-install, you can assume the setup is complete and check the functionality you desire from Cygwin and see if it works.

Comment: Addition to previous comment: if you are not re-installing then you might be missing the desktop icon to start Cygwin. You can create a shortcut using target as 'C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -'

Comment: I actually am not able to find a "reinstall" or "upgrade" option. Where do I get this? Is it a separate executable from the usual "setup" ?

Comment: http://cygwin.com/index.html . See the links at top left. Install and upgrade are same. Cygwin will take care of identifying what you have already installed. If you follow exact steps, the upgrade procedure will not take much time, may be around a minute or so. For general guidelines - http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/cygwin/

Comment: I ran the update and get the following "Postinstall script error:" Unknown package autorebase.bat exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but —

- When `mandb.exe` hung, I killed its parent `bash.exe` via Task Manager and the installation completed.
- I then killed `mandb.exe` in Task Manager, since it was still running.
- I then opened a Cygwin shell and ran `mandb -cds`.  `-c` recreates the index, `-d` prints messages (so you can actually tell it's doing something constructive!) and `-s` suppresses checking for orphaned formatted manual pages (["stray cats"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185359/63804)).

As I write this, `mandb` is still chugging along, three or four hours later, with plenty yet to go.

So I'll remember to file a bug report later :) , I did notice one oddity during the mandb run:

```
mandb: /usr/share/man/man3/jN.3 is self referencing
mandb: warning: /usr/share/man/man3/jnf.3.gz: bad symlink or ROFF `.so' request
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem today until I realised that moving the main Cygwin setup window revealed a popup complaining about "can't open (null) for reading: no such file"

This happens multiple times in a (re)install